# Do Client-only Version Control programs exist?

Tags: svn, version-control, dvcs, cvcs

I'm working with a small team on multiple websites all stored on a server. We don't have the ability to install software on said server space, so basically think of it as a shared hard drive.

The team is not really familiar with version / revision control, and they're going to be really resistant to anything that isn't really painless.

We just need a simple way to track changes and lock files. No need for fancy merging or anything like that.

Is there a revision control system that is completely client-side? For example, my client version control program leaves a note about which files I check out on the shared drive. When someone else tries to check them out, their client program doesn't let them, because it's locked. When I check back in, it keeps a dated copy of the file that can be reverted to later.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't mix "Version Control" with "Deploy" - they are different processes for different purposes, thus - VCS host and deploy target can be and are (usually) different hosts
2. Only *CVCS as class* support locking model (in DVCS-world "one developer-one /own/ repository" model used strictly and merges are every-day task)
3. In any case, you **must** to migrate from the "as it grew" workflow to "as it should be". Somehow easiest way may be (it does not remove the need to study and understand at least the basics of VCS and Subversion)

   - Subversion
   - [Assembla's Subversion hosting](http://offers.assembla.com/free-subversion-hosting/)
   - [EasySVN](http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/79174/Simplify-Subversion-with-this-EasySVN-for-Windows-release.aspx) (can be found now only [outside of Assembla](http://download.cnet.com/EasySVN/3000-2229_4-75703158.html))
   - FTP|SSH tool in Assembla space in order to deploy changes on hosting-server

Answer (score 0):

You just have a slight terminological confusion.  "Client-only" means "serverless", and any DVCS (that is, a Distributed VCS) *is* autonomous, that is, serverless which, in turn, might mean "client-only" if you like.

To say this differently, any DVCS keeps a complete record of all the history recorded in any repository it manages.  Most (all?) DVCSes support "sharing" this history—through "pushing" and "fetching"—but are not at all oblidged to do that.

So just pick Git, Mercurial, Fossil or whatever else DVCS which suits your needs.

---

A caveat.

DVCSes usually do not support locking—precisely because they're free-standing.
Locking is considered to be an articast of the past by many (merges should be used instead) but still locks might have their legitimate uses.  If you positively can't live without locks then take another direction: Subversion might work in "serverless" mode by using the `file://` repository access scheme, and it supports locks.

Comment: The problem with the DVCS approach is that everyone will have separate repositories.  Based on the problem description, I think that is undesirable.  The question specifies that merging isn't desired.  SVN sounds plausible though.

Comment: I have the impression that the team is using the live server as code repository and they just want a mechanism to warn others ("hey, I'm editing foo.c please don't touch it"). That can hardly be called source control with modern standards.

Comment: Merges are ok if locking doesn't happen, the main thing is that others have to be prevented from overwriting things, and a record of versions needs to be kept. Git will be too complex for the team to get used to, unless there is some awesome GUI version that will work. I haven't used the others you mentioned, I'll look into them.

Comment: Atlassian SourceTree is the closest thing I've seen to an awesome GUI version of git.